# How to use java sample as sample data in Transform Message in Mule?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a sample java input into the Dataweave that I copied from the debugger in Anypoint Studio which looks like this:

```
result=[{Office=NYC, Dept=Sales, EmployeeCount=1000}]
```

I want to use it as sample data for the input in dataweave and copied it into the edit sample data section and nothing happens in the preview window even though the dataweave code is just:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload
```

How can I use the java above with the preview mode in transform message?

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.2 and Mule 3.8.3.

Thanks

Comment: let me know if below solution works for you

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you giving sample data in a right way using dwl.

Try below flow to build your contruct,this works perfectly fine and generates a preview with sample data,check images below -

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" basePath="/testapi" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="uri">
    <http:listener path="uri/{param}/resource" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" >
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\string.dwl" mimeType="application/java"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
</flow>
```

Custom Java object used in this case looks like :
**MyTest.java**

```
public class MyTest {

    String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    int age;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyTest [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

**Input payload mapping(Context)**
[image]

**Sample input payload**
[image]

Comment: @user3165854 , let us know if this solution worked for you.This might help others visiting this page for same query.And kindly accept the answer if so.